# Math processing error and other issues with MathJax in Safari

Tags: bug, mathjax

These days I frequently encounter MathJax problems as shown in the figure below. Even if I reload the page a few times, the issue remains. This seems to happen on and off. Am I the only one having such issues?

1.

[image]

2.

[image]

**EDIT:**

I took the image from Bill's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142898/puzzle-cumulative-sum-divisible-by-10/142928#142928). I cleared the browser cache yesterday (before J.D pointed out) and it worked fine. However, I encountered the issue again now. This bug appears on Safari Mac OS X snow-leopard.

**EDIT: (May 11th, 2012)**
I again encountered this problem for the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111850/a-galois-group-problem).
[image]

Comment: My experience is that putting $\color{red}{\textit{[Math Processing Error]}}$ usually solves my problem as well!

Comment: @Asaf Heh. Note that the errors arise only after introducing a phantom. Berekeley would have a field day with that. "But what are these phantoms? The reifications of evanescent expressions? And what are these same evanescent expressions? They are neither finite quantities, nor quantities infinitely small, nor yet nothing. May we not call them the ghosts of departed expressions?" No wonder MathJax blew up.

Comment: @Bill, quite poetic. I'd imagine that these phantom expressions are like generic reals over some model of set theory. They are echoed by the reals in the ground, but these traces are nothing more than finite approximations. Never the reals themselves.

Comment: It is hard to tell what is going on if we cannot see the source that is being rendered.  Just taking a screenshot of the $\color{red}{\textit{[Math Processing Error]}}$ doesn't give much to go on.

Comment: @Asaf Those are Berkeley's words, mod a few changes (fluxion -> phantom, etc). Compare [Hankel's similar critique](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2658) of Cauchy's definition of imaginary number: 'There must be something "which means nothing or "which is assigned a different value than it should naturally be" something that has "no sense"...coupled with another similar kind, producing something real... I do not think I'm exaggerating in calling this an unintelligible play on words, ill-becoming of mathematics, which is proud and rightly proud of the clarity and evidence of its concepts.'

Comment: @robjohn It's from my answer [here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/142928/242) Jokes aside, most likely, it has nothing to do with the particular $\LaTeX$ code but, rather, has to do with some external state.

Comment: @Bill: Thanks for the reference. That answer renders fine for me. However, I had a [similar problem](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4118/mathjax-bug-upon-page-refresh) recently where the problem was not buggy $\LaTeX$, but had I just posted an image, I think that Davide Cervone would have had a much harder time finding the problem.

Comment: Clearing browser cache might work..

Comment: @J.D.Yes I did that and it works for sometime but then again it crops up after a day or two.

Comment: As with all bug reports, I suggest you include the various operation systems, architectures and browsers (with  versions) which were involved in the process.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes. I have added the info now.

Comment: The screen shot of Bill's answer shows a mixture of untypeset math with "Math Processing Errors"; is that the case in your other examples as well (the screen shots don't show far enough down the page to see whether there are processing errors farther on).  I'm wondering it isn't the same basic issue as Bill's link (a failure to properly recover after a restart for asynchronous file load).  I am not able to reproduce the problem, though.  Is anyone else seeing this?  @Marvis, can you try disabling the STIX fonts in FontBook for a test?

Comment: @DavideCervone I do not see the [Math Processing Errors] now. But I still see have untypeset math even now for the second question.

Comment: @marvis:  Thanks for the info.  I'm updating my system now to try to get 5.1.7 to experiment with (but it's 10.7 not 10.6).  We'll see.  In the meantime, do you have any extensions or other modifications to Safari?  Did you try disabling the STIX fonts?

Comment: @DavideCervone The problem occurs on 10.7 as well. The only extension I have on safari is Adblock. There are no other modifications to Safari. I tried disabling the STIX fonts but it does not help. Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: @Marvis, I'm not sure I've helped yet, but I'm trying!

Comment: @Marvis, After updating to Safari 5.1.7 on Mac OS X 10.7.4, I'm still not able to reproduce the issue.  For now, can you try switching to the SVG output rather than HTML-CSS and see if that renders?

Comment: @Marvis, I think the issue is related to [this bug](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3942/7798).  Your screen shots show MathJax the phase where it is measuring the font sizes and column widths, and it has crashed during that process somewhere.  This is similar to the situation where the TeX input processor had a bug, but that doesn't seem to be the case here, since only you are seeing it.  Can you type `javascript:alert(MathJax.Message.Log())` in the URL location and see if there are any "failed to load" messages?

Comment: @DavideCervone I went to the page where the typeset failed and typed and got the following `Loading [MathJax]/config/TeX-AMS_HTML.js
Loading [MathJax]/jax/element/mml/optable/GreekAndCoptic.js
Loading [MathJax]/jax/output/HTML-CSS/jax.js
Loading [MathJax]/jax/output/HTML-CSS/fonts/TeX/fontdata.js
Error preparing HTML-CSS output (preProcess)
Loading Web-Font TeX/Math/Italic
Loading Web-Font TeX/Main/Regular
Loading [MathJax]/jax/output/HTML-CSS/fonts/TeX/AMS/Regular/Main.js
Loading Web-Font TeX/Size1/Regular`

Comment: Ok, that indicates an error during the measurement phase as I suspected. Now if you go to that page, after MathJax runs, try typing `javascript:alert(MathJax.Hub.lastPrepError.message)` into the URL location.  Let's hope that holds something useful.

Comment: @DavideCervone I am on a different comp now. I shall try it this evening and keep you posted. Thanks.

Comment: @DavideCervone I am not sure if I did correctly what you wanted me to. I get the following

`'undefined' is not an object`

Comment: Was it on the page that produced the math processing errors?  The `lastPrepError` will only be defined on a page that has produced the error message shown in your original message log.  You might check that first to see that there is a preProcess error.

Comment: @DavideCervone http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4221/does-this-question-seem-to-have-formatting-problems also reports of similar problems for Safari on Mac osX Lion